# import rang in spreadsheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, spreadsheet

i need to import data from another document 
but i need to choose sheet name from the the other sheet which contains importrang formula 
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-cobWuroV9l1at4hlcPjc8-Vqc6AV0XLj7_7k5AIT3Y/edit","sam!A1:A4")

i need sheet name (here its sam) to be chosen from drop down list
e.g i have 4 sheets
if he choose sam it will bring data from sam sheet
if he choose dan it will bring data from dan sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a dropdown for instance in A1 containing all the relevant sheet names

In A2:  `=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-cobWuroV9l1at4hlcPjc8-Vqc6AV0XLj7_7k5AIT3Y/edit",indirect(A1&"!A1:A4"))`